# MySQL + PHP - Select info based on previous select result

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm doing an integration of PHP and MySQL.
The following code is working fine:

```
<?php
include_once("conf.php");

$sql = "SELECT Name,Address FROM customers";
$rs = mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die("can't connect to DB");
$temp = mysqli_num_rows($rs);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
{
  $convert = mb_convert_encoding ($row['Name'],"UTF-8","gbk");
  $print .= "<tr><td>".$convert."</td><td>".$row['Address']."</td><td>".$sql2."</td></tr>\n";
}
```

This code is working, but now I need to select specific information from ANOTHER table, BASED on the result (Name) of this one.

So, this would be the other MySQL select:

```
$sql2 = "select History from Delivery where Name="$convert";
```

Based on the **"Name"** of my customer (from customer table), I need to get his **"History"** at the **Delivery** table.

So, I will print his: Name + Address + History

What would be the best solution??

@@@@@@@@@ SOLVED @@@@@@@@@@

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers c 
            INNER JOIN Delivery d 
            ON c.Name = d.Name';

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$temp = mysqli_num_rows($rs);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result))
{
  $convert = mb_convert_encoding ($row['Name'],"UTF-8","gbk");
  $print .= "<tr><td>".$convert."</td><td>".$row['Address']."</td><td>".$row['History']."</td></tr>\n";
}
```

My current situation is: I have three tables from which I need to get info.

Tables: customers, users, history.

From customers I need ammount of customers.

From Delivery I need History (based on ammount of customers).

From users I need Name (actually it's almost a nickname).

**Since that these three tables have a 'Name' column and I CAN'T change column names, how can I get the Name from USERS instead of CUSTOMERS or DELIVERY using that INNER JOIN statement??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a join on the first table to grab all the data you need at one time:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers c 
            INNER JOIN Delivery d 
            ON c.Name = d.Name';

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result))
{
    echo $row['History'] . ' ' . $row['Name'];
}
```

This saves you from needing the second query.

Comment: I don't get it...
How would I print that?

Comment: @Darkeden - I've added a more complete example

Comment: I just figured out.
Now I'm using INNER JOIN.
I was trying to use custom columns instead of all columns (*).
Thank you NickB

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to do an INNER JOIN with these two tables on name?

Answer (score 1):

Darkeden, you can do SELECT customers.* or you could do SELECT customers.name as 'CName' and etc.  Using aliases like this, you can later do echo $row['CName'].

Comment: customers.* = customers.Name ??
Like: SELECT * FROM customers c 
            INNER JOIN Delivery d 
            ON users.Name as 'c.Name' = users.Name as 'd.Name'';

Comment: Instead of selecting * (every column from every table), you could select customers.* which would select each column from the table customers.  In that case, you would know that 'name' would be the customer's name.  You'll want to only select the columns that you're using.  You can still use columns in the where clause even if you are not using them in the select statement.

Comment: 'SELECT users.* FROM customers c 
            INNER JOIN Delivery d 
            ON c.Name = d.Name
            INNER JOIN users e
            ON d.Name = e.Name';

Comment: SELECT users.id as 'userID', users.name as 'userName' etc.

Comment: and then "...from customers..." ?

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT c.Name as 'customerName', c.Id as 'customerID', d.Date as 'deliveryDate' FROM customers c 
            INNER JOIN Delivery d 
            ON c.Name = d.Name'; etc

Comment: Thank you. Isn't what exactly what I need, but it's way better now, thanks.